# Group by Date Field in Element API Query

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi, elementquery

I have a custom field called releaseDate in one of my entry types. I would like to use Element API to get all the distinct years assigned to those entries. I dump all the years for all entries just fine like this:

```
'endpoints' => [
    'api/v1/release_years' => function () {
    return [
        'class' => EntryResource::class,
        'elementType' => Entry::class,
        'criteria' => [
            'section' => 'products',
            'orderBy' => 'field_releaseDate',
            'where' => 'field_releaseDate IS NOT NULL',
//          'groupBy' => '????????'
        ],
        'transformer' => function (Entry $entry) {
            return [$entry->releaseDate->format('Y')];
        },
        'pretty' => true
    ];
}
```

But the minute I add a group clause to the criteria section, it fails. I've tried the following:

```
'groupBy' => 'YEAR(field_relaseDate)'

'groupBy' => 'YEAR(relaseDate)'

'groupBy' => 'field_releaseDate.year'

'groupBy' => 'releaseDate.year'

'group' => 'YEAR(field_relaseDate)'

'group' => 'YEAR(relaseDate)'

'group' => 'field_releaseDate.year'

'group' => 'releaseDate.year'
```

Any ideas if this is even possible? Also does anyone know if you can return a single array from Element API instead of a multi-level array? This output seems a bit inefficient:

```
'data' = [
    [2010],
    [2011],
    [2012],
    [2013],
    [2014],
    [2015],
    [2016],
    [2017],
    [2018],
    [2019],
]
```

I would much prefer:

```
'data' = [
    2011,
    2012,
    2013,
    2014,
    2015,
    2016,
    2017,
    2018,
    2019
]
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Nope. I ended up making another entry type for release years and using a hook to add data dynamically to it. It ended up working ok since we eventually had to add other meta data to the release years.